# Show that $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ is a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$, $p_1=1 +2x+x^2$, $p_2= 2+9x$, and $p_3=3+3x+4x^2$ is a basis for $p_2$. Express $p$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors where $p= 2 +17x-3x^2$.

I understand how something can be a basis for say real numbers but I dont understand how $p_2$ can be a basis and a part of the set. I also know that for something to be a set it needs to span the original set and be linearly independent but the $p_2$ basis is what I think I am having trouble with.

Comment: Matt, you use $p_2$ for both a polynomial and for the whole vector space. Probably want $P^2$ for the space of polynomials of degree $2$ or less?

Comment: You mean a basis for $P_2 = \{ p | p \text{ has degree at most } 2 \}$?

Comment: Always mind your 'p's...

Comment: That is why I am so confused on this problem but sadly no. Lets assume that my proffesor had a typo (which happens on every homework assignment) and that it is P has degree at most 2

Comment: Then you need to show that if you have $p(x) = a+bx+cx^2$ then you can find $\alpha_k$ such that $p = \sum_k \alpha_k p_k$. Then you need to show that if $\sum_k \beta_k p_k = 0$, then $\beta_k = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The professor is asking you to find real numbers $\alpha_{j}$ so that
$$
         p = \alpha_1 p_1 + \alpha_2 p_2 + \alpha_3 p_3.
$$
When you write that out:
$$
\begin{align}
    2+17x-3x^{2} & =\alpha_1 (1+2x+x^{2})+\alpha_2(2+9x)+\alpha_3(3+3x+4x^{2}) \\
           & = (\alpha_1+2\alpha_2+3\alpha_3) \\
           & + (2\alpha_1+9\alpha_2+3\alpha_3)x \\
           & + (\alpha_1+4\alpha_3)x^{2}
\end{align}
$$
Now equate coefficients of $1$, $x$, $x^{2}$ and try to solve.